Add component selector as text above every custom component in Angular
I repeatedly look for component selector with inspector (Example: app-custom-component) when developing Angular apps. Which made me think. Can I simply show the value of selector above every component in Angular on top:0, left:0. I want to achieve this without modifying component(s). No base class no additional decorator or anything like that. Also it is desirable to disable this completely for prod environments for perf reasons (assumption)
I went several blind alleys:

PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES is arguably the best fit, however it's deprecated
supplying custom Renderer2 - this felt just wrong and seems like could cause issues (no idea what I'm doing)
selector "*" on a directive - this was suggested by LLM but simply is not a thing


If you're using the browser to explore your codebase, the DevTools plugin might be all you need. It allows selecting an element on the page and seeing relevant information about the Angular component(s) it belongs to as well as their internal state.
If you don't want to use the plugin and you only care about developer environments, something like this might be simpler than trying to hook the Renderer2:
function labelNgComponents() {
  
  // Template the label we'll be using so we can
  // efficiently clone it for each component.
  const labelTemplate = document.createElement('div');
  labelTemplate.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelTemplate.style.top = 0;
  labelTemplate.style.left = 0;
  labelTemplate.style.border = '1px solid red';
  labelTemplate.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  labelTemplate.style.zIndex = 100;
  
  // Remove labels inserted into the DOM by previous
  // runs of this function.
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('debug-label'))
       .forEach(node => node.remove());
  
  // Find all element nodes in the DOM. These are the
  // candidates for Angular component hosts.
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.getRootNode(), 
                                           NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
  
  while(walker.nextNode()) {

    // We'll use the node itself for DOM manipulation.
    const node = walker.currentNode;

    // Check if the node is an Angular component host.
    // This would also allow us to access state information.
    // The `window.ng` object is provided by Angular when
    // the application is in debug mode.
    const component = ng.getComponent(node);
    if (component != null)
    {

        // Label the node using its selector (the case
        // will vary because `Node.nodeName` is stored
        // in all caps).
        const label = labelTemplate.cloneNode();
        label.textContent = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        label.classList.add('debug-label');
        node.appendChild(label);
    }
  }
}

Just copy/paste it into the terminal while you're running your application in debug mode and then execute the function any time you want to update the label(s).

this is awesome, thanks you. For what its worth Angular DevTools never worked for me reliably -- it could be my app I dunno but never the less I stopped using it. This on the other hand is really cool
